# Setting height of canvas to cover entirety of scrollable page

Tags: javascript, css, html, html5-canvas

My canvas element currently has the following attributes:

```
var c = document.getElementById("c");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

    //making the canvas full screen
    c.height = window.innerHeight;
    c.width = window.innerWidth;
```

When I place the canvas on a page which has more content than can fit in the height of the screen, the canvas cuts off when I scroll down, which is to be expected. How do I change the height property to get the canvas to extend as far down as there is content on the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
    var c = document.getElementById("c");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

    //making the canvas full screen
    c.height = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].scrollHeight;
    c.width = window.innerWidth;
```

Comment: There is `scrollWidth` for width as well.